# in Pandas Dataframe, after I set an entire column, I can't update another column with times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe. One column is a timestamp, and another is boolean. When I set the entire boolean column at once, I can no longer update anything in the timestamp column - when I try, it doesn't complain, but the value doesn't change. Here's a simplified example:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('20140401')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DateRange(start,periods=1), columns=['timenow','Live'])
df.at[start,'timenow'] = datetime.today() # initial value
print(df)
df.at[start,'timenow'] = datetime.today() # this works
print(df)
df.Live = True
df.at[start,'timenow'] = datetime.today() # this doesn't work - nothing changes
print(df)
```

I would expect to see 3 distinct times, but instead the 2nd time stays put when I try to change it:

```
                              timenow Live
2014-04-01 2014-04-24 01:33:30.037108  NaN
[1 rows x 2 columns]
                              timenow Live
2014-04-01 2014-04-24 01:33:30.040039  NaN
[1 rows x 2 columns]
                              timenow  Live
2014-04-01 2014-04-24 01:33:30.040039  True
[1 rows x 2 columns]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: this is a bug, use ``.loc`` instead of ``.at``.

Comment: @Jeff, it is something to do with `datetime`?

Comment: see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6942; their is some logic in ``.loc`` which is not happening with ``.at`` (as its meant to be quicker access), so maybe not updating dtype correctly, PR's welcome!

Comment: @fantabolous, FYI. In general its better to create the frame with the data as a dict/array/list, rather than set individually (its more efficient)

Comment: Thanks Jeff, .loc did the trick! I had read somewhere that for single field reference .at was faster and didn't think to try .loc. Btw in my actual use case the majority of the frame gets created up front, but then I need to update some fields as other work gets done.

Comment: Just a note, I've found that .at is at least 10 times faster than .loc or .ix when setting individual cells. It's even faster to do a for loop with .at than to use .ix with a range. Relevant when updating 100000's of cells. The caveat is .at doesn't work with datetimes (and maybe others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably working on the a view rather than the data directly, this should work:

```
df.loc[start,'timenow']= datetime.today()
print df
```

Comment: I don't think it's a view issue as I'm accessing a single point. In fact the docs specifically say to set individual points using .at because it's faster. That said, .loc does work (as per Jeff's comment above). Thanks.